# what does the "logged" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recently read a passage which has a sentence

> The fire was located in the basement and the four-story building was heavily smoke logged, he said.

I understand all words except the "logged". It seems that no meaning in the dictionary fits it. struggle on it.

Answer (score 2):

Smoke-logged (generally would have a hyphen) means filled or almost filled with smoke. Like water-logged, which means filled with water.

Answer (score 1):

To be "smoke logged" just means to be filled with smoke.

> The term "smoke logged" as used in Figure 1 refers to a compartment that is filled (or largely filled) with smoke. ([Source: Reading the Fire: Smoke and Air Track](https://www.firehouse.com/operations-training/article/10504806/reading-the-fire-smoke-and-air-track))

Comment: Looks like this is a technical usage unique to firefighters - I've never heard it before; in ordinary conversation this use of "-logged" to mean "saturated with" is only ever used in "water-logged".  No wonder the original poster couldn't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: @A.B. Absolutely. I admit I had to Google and read 2 or 3 sources to make sure I get it right.